# How to convert NSArray to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdate

I am having an array which having a date. I want to convert the array into NSDate. Then converted NSDate are stored in an another array.This is my array.

```
uniqueItems (
 "2015-02-17",
"2015-02-09",
"2015-02-02",
"2015-01-27",
"2015-01-19",
"2015-01-12"
)
```

How to convert this array to NSDate, And store in to another array. Help me in coding.

Comment: Why dont you try for your self, its easy. enumerate this array with for each loop, you will get string. make date formatter & convert them to date & store them to a mutable array. done !

Comment: Hello All, Please dont discourage to anyone.. Else we can Write comment as pawan. May be that person is newbie so he/she dont understand and he/she wants to learn...

Comment: Whats wrong with encouraging some newbie to write code on his own. if he failed to do this , he can always return here for help with his tried code. *Most importent , stackoverflow is not a platform to write code for someone*

Comment: @pawan @ Er.shreyansh shah Thanks for your care and advice.

Comment: One last advice , dont create nsdateformatter with in for each loop, but make it before the for loop or better declare it in interface. because nsdateformatter are so costly, they take a huge processing time & memory at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert your NSString to NSDate

```
NSArray *arrr = @[ @"2015-02-17",
                   @"2015-02-09",
                   @"2015-02-02",
                   @"2015-01-27",
                   @"2015-01-19",
                   @"2015-01-12"];
NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];           
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
for (int i = 0; i<arrr.count; i++) {
    [arrDates addObject:[df dateFromString:arrr[i]];;
}
NSLog(@"%@",arrDates);
```

now sort array for dates because your array contains NSDate Objects. you don't have key so do not pass any key

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@""
                                    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedDateArray = [arrDates sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedDateArray);
```

Comment: arrDates are getting null value

Comment: i've use `arrr` you have to use your array and pass your array `NSDate *dd = [df dateFromString:yourArray[i]];` and make sure you alloc init `arrDates ` using `NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; `

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have an array as below:

```
NSArray *ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2015-02-17",@"2015-02-09",@"2015-02-02", nil];
```

To convert each string into date:-

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
for(int i =0;i<ary.count;i++){

    NSDate *d = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    d = [dateFormatter dateFromString:ary[i]];
}
```

If you want to use **NSDateFormate**, you can also use in  loop also.

Comment: it will return NSString object you have to convert it in NSDate Object and for that you need dateformatter and then convert it.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani :- Thank you chintan for help. This is just a demo or prototype as i write in last, if you want to use Dateformatter than u can use in loop.

Comment: You must have to use it otherwise you won't get NSDate Object.

Comment: you can try and check its class so you may know.

Comment: @GowthamK :- Do you want any specific format so i can edit in that format only.

Comment: @ Er.shreyansh Shah I got it bro. thanks for your care.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand as you are a newbie,Follow these steps but remember to get the understanding first:-

1.Enumerate your array to get all the strings(dates for your understanding),and add those to another array you want, like this:-

```
for (NSString *dateString in yourArrayofDates) {
    NSDate *date=[self getDateFromDateString:dateString];
    [yourAnotherDateArray addObject:date];
 }
```

2.Add a method to get the NSDate from your string,like this:-

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromDateString :(NSString *)dateString {
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
return date;
}
```